# Actionscript Image with clickable spots

Tags: actionscript-3

Can any one help in suggesting a solution for the following:

i have a large image, consider it as a map, i want to put this image in a viewer that is smaller than the image and i have to be able to scroll the image by clicking and dragging it.
and i want to put in this image a clickable spots in a specified x and y coordinated, and be able to click the spots.

when clicking any spot in the image, the image will be changed with a new spots.. and so on..

can you help in suggesting what is the best object to load the image in and be able to do all the mentioned points.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier than you think.  You have a few goals to consider:

1. "i want to put this image in a viewer that is smaller than the image": You dont need anything special to do this.  The concept of this is simply that you have a mask overlay where you want the large image visible.

   ```
   var viewer:Sprite = new Sprite;             //200x200
   var imageMask:Sprite = new Sprite;          //200x200
   var imageContainer:Sprite = new Sprite;     //400x500

   imageContainer.mask = imageMask;
   viewer.addChild(imageContainer);

   //this will allow you to visibly see only 200x200 of the 
   //imageContainer at any time
   ```
2. "i have to be able to scroll the image by clicking and dragging it":  This is a little more logic as the imageContainer will have to move in the -(negative) direction of the mouse.  Add some listeners to check for mouse actions, and drag as required.

   ```
   var allowDrag:Boolean = false;

   imageContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
   imageContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
   imageContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);

   function onMouseDown(e:Event):void{
       allowDrag = true;
   }

   function onMouseUp(e:Event):void{
       allowDrag = false;
   }

   function onMouseMove(e:Event):void{

       //return if not dragging
       if(!allowDrag) return;

       //move the imageContainer in a -(negative) direction of the mouse
       //use an index relative to the size of the viewer and imageContainer
       var speed:Number = 0.5;
       imageContainer.x -= (viewer.width/imageContainer.width)*speed;
       imageContainer.y -= (viewer.height/imageContainer.height)*speed;

       //clean the positions so the image remains within the viewer
       if(imageContainer.x > 0) imageContainer.x = 0;
       if(imageContainer.x < -viewer.width) imageContainer.x = -viewer.width;
       if(imageContainer.y > 0) imageContainer.y = 0;
       if(imageContainer.y < -viewer.height) imageContainer.y = -viewer.height;
   }
   ```
3. "i want to put in this image a clickable spots in a specified x and y coordinated, and be able to click the spots": This also requires a little more thinking.  In this case what you want to do is create [hotspots] on the image that are clickable, when clicked = do actions.

   ```
   //USAGE

   //define the click area coords
   var clickCoords:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
   clickCoords.x = 10;         //starts at x 10
   clickCoords.y = 10;         //starts at y 10
   clickCoords.width = 100;    //100 wide
   clickCoords.height = 100;   //100 tall

   //add the click listener
   var clickArea:Sprite = hotSpot(imageContainer,clickCoords);
   clickArea.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onHotSoptClick);

   //hot spot factory
   function hotSpot(target:Sprite,coords:Rectangle):Sprite{

       //create the hotspot
       var hs:Sprite = new Sprite;
       hs.graphics.beginFill(0,0);
       hs.graphics.drawRect(0,0,coords.width,coords.height);
       hs.graphics.endFill();

       //add the hotspot to the target
       hs.x = coords.x;
       hs.y = coords.y;
       target.addChild(hs);

   }

   function onHotSoptClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
       //do something
   }
   ```

IMPORTANT:
You may want to keep a list of hot spots you create so you can do garbage cleanup, and you plan on dynamically generating hotspots per image... then YOU MUST keep an active list of hot spots and remove when not in use.

Comment: we can use startDrag() and stopDrag()

Comment: Yes you can use start/stop drag at any point... or just update the position of the element based on the mouse x/y... either/or.  But you should consider that start/stop draw will not allow you to add variances, such as speed and timing to the dragging.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the events MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove, MouseOut, on your viewing window, this way you can control exactly what do you want to do.
Here is the pseudo-code:

```
reset()
{
  isDown=false;
  downPointX=0;
  downPointY=0;
  distanceX=0;
  distanceY=0;
}

onMouseDown()
{
  isDown=true;
  downPointX=mouseX;
  downPointY=mouseY;
}

onMouseUp()
{
  if(distanceX+distanceY==0 and isDown)
    click(downPointX,downPointY);
  reset();
}

onMouseMove()
{
  if isDown then
    distanceX=mouseX-downPointX;
    distanceY=mouseY-downPointY;
    drag(distanceX,distanceY);
  endif;
}

onMouseOut()
{
  reset();
} 

drag(distanceX,distanceY)
{
  change your map coordinates
}

click(downPointX,downPointY)
{
  if(inSpot(downPointX,downPointY)==true)
    changeMap();
  endif;
}

changeMap()
{
  change your maps and spots
}
```

avoid implementing any event for your spots sprites or you can get unexpected results.

You can check these for more information
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#eventSummary

Comment: Thanks,
so it is better to load the main image in a sprite?
i loaded the main image in a sprite(1) and this sprite is child to another sprite(2), as i change the width of sprite(2), the main image is resized, but i want to keep its initial size and view just the part viewed by sprite(2)

Comment: You could use a sprite(container) with a child(map) cliped with a mask
Take a look at this http://www.streamhead.com/tutorial-applying-manipulating-mask-actionscript-3/ Its really close to your need, in this case is the mask that is moving, in your case it would be the background

Comment: ok thanks, i was afraid that the mask will prevent me from clicking on spots, but it seems the mask is just an 'open window'